# How to prevent daily and lifetime relationship meter from going down

Tags: the-sims-2

I have made a lot of friends and have boosted their relationship meter to maximum (100). Time goes very fast in the sims 2 and I don't have enough time to telephone all of those friends to keep them friends. Is there any cheat that prevents their daily and lifetime relatiohship meter from going down? (don't tell me to kill them. that's ludicrous)

Comment: `don't tell me to kill them. that's ludicrous` Hmm... is *"die"* a valid answer? ;)

Comment: Some guys say that by killing family friends, they will remain friends permanently.

Comment: Is this for PC or console? The distinction made in the title imply it's PC, because I've never heard of two different relationship meters.

Comment: You could exploit the way time stops when you visit a community lot. Invite multiple friends on an outing. Or invite several over for dinner, which fills the Hunger, Comfort, and Social needs simultaneously while maintaining relationships.